# Creating a chess board with variable square size

Tags: c++

I have a class called Image in C++, where I have a width, and height and a long vector which stores all the pixel values in a manner, that it iterates through the first column, then it moves one row down, iterates through the second column etc.. ( 0 ist black, 255 is white )

Now I have written a function void chess (), that transforms the pixel values in such a way that it has the basic chess pattern on it, when you 
give it out.

**My next idea is to create chess board with varying size,e.g. width 8, height 8, and each square of the chessboard is 2x2 pixels instead of 
1x1**

Now, if I try to implement it, my only "idea" is to use 2 counters, one to track that it changes from white to black not after every pixel, but after the new size of pixels. Additionally, you'd have to have a second counter to keep track, after how many rows you have to invert, so you start with black, instead of white.

Yet I can't figure it out, I end up with so many If statements and for and while loops, that it always comes out messy. There has to be a significantly easier way. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
class Image
{
public:
    typedef uint16_t PixelType;

private:
    int width_;
    int height_;
    std::vector<PixelType> data_;

public:
    // Standardkonstruktor: initialisiere Bild mit Groesse (0,0)
    Image()
    : width_(0)
    , height_(0)
    {}

    Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    : width_(width)
      , height_(height)
    {
        int size = width * height;

        for(int j=0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < width; i++)
            {
                data_.push_back(0);
            }
        }
    }

    void chess() // change an image to chess board pattern
    {
        data_.clear();
        int width = (*this).width();
        int height = (*this).height();

        for(int w=0; w < width; w++)
        {
            for(int h=1; h <= height; h++)
            {
                /*std::cout << "P=("+ std::to_string(w) + "," + std::to_string(h) + ")" << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::to_string(h%2) <<std::endl;
                for testing purposes only */
                if(w%2==0)
                {
                    if( !(h%2==0) )
                    {
                        data_.push_back(255);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data_.push_back(0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if( !(h%2==0) )
                    {
                        data_.push_back(0);
                    } else
                    {
                        data_.push_back(255);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: off topic: your constructor could be just one line data_.resize(width*height,0);    or even better Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    : width_(width)
    , height_(height),
data_(width * height,0)
    {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try coloring the matrix based on the parity of the w and h. If w+h is even color black else color white. Start with both h and w from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually better to allocate the vector first (as pointed out in @Humam 's comment to your question) and then just setting it's values.

Suppose you want your cells to be `n x n` pixels size (I hope you check width and height to be divisible by `n`). One solution can be something like this:

```
void chess(int n)                          // pass n as parameter or as you want
{
    ...

    bool isBlackCell = true;               // change to false to start with a white one

    for(int h=0; h < height; h+=n)
    {
        for(int w=0; w < width; w+=n)
        {
            // now fill the whole cell
            for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                for (int j=0; j < n; ++j)
                {
                    data_[(h+i)*size+w+j] = isBlackCell ? 0 : 255;
                }
            }

            // switch to another color as we moving to another 'cell'
            isBlackCell = !isBlackCell;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This is straightforward but a bit inefficient because of painful cache misses

**Edit 1:** Let me explain what this `data_[(h+i)*w+w+j]` does: as you store your pixel data row after row, so `(h+i)*size` skips `(h+i)` rows and then comes to current pixel position adding `w+j`